# Registry Edit -->winRM-->Client--> basic authentication resets the value to 0,when i set the value to 1

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, basic-authentication, azure-powershell, regedit

for execution of Powershell script requires basic auth true on windows server But when i set it true using regedit after some time it resets to 0.

Registry Edit-->winRM-->Client-->Basic Auth resets the value after some time to 0,when i set the value to 1.

Any other solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an "issue" where a GPO expect basic auth to not be allowed, hence this being reset regularly.

Comment: @notjustme Is this a expected behavior of system?

Comment: Well, I know nothing about your environment but assuming you're in a Windows domain, Active Directory if you will, this is expected behavior if there is a policy in place for this particular setting to be 0.

Comment: @notjustme we are using windows server 2016.